# Python: Comparing Hierarchies in C4D

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, cinema-4d

Wondering what I am doing wrong here, I am trying to compare hierarchies so that I can link items with the same name together with PSR tags, when forming my lists from two separate hierarchies (first_sel_list and second_sel_list) I get extra results in my reduced lists.

```
    first_sel_list = ['First_Null', 'Cube', 'Cube.1', 'Cube.2', 'Cube.3', 'Cube.4', 'Cube.5', 'Cube.6', 'Ignore_Top_0', 'Ignore_Top_1', 'Ignore_Top_2', 'Ignore_Top_Child_00', 'Ignore_Top_Child_01', 'Ignore_Top_Child_02', 'Ignore_Top_Child_03', 'Cube.7']
    
    second_sel_list = ['Second_Null', 'Cube', 'Cube.1', 'Cube.2', 'Cube.3', 'Shit_Bot_0', 'Ignore_Bot_1', 'Ignore_Bot_2', 'Cube.4', 'Cube.6', 'Cube.7', 'Cube.5']
    
    link_list = ['Cube', 'Cube.1', 'Cube.2', 'Cube.3', 'Cube.4', 'Cube.5', 'Cube.6', 'Cube.7']
    
    for name in first_sel_list:
        if name not in link_list:
            first_sel_list.remove(name)
    for name in second_sel_list:
        if name not in link_list:
            second_sel_list.remove(name)
                
    
    print ('LINK LIST ' + str(link_list))        
    print ('Edited First list ' + str(first_sel_list))
    print ('Edited Second list ' + str(second_sel_list))
```

Output:

```
LINK LIST ['Cube', 'Cube.1', 'Cube.2', 'Cube.3', 'Cube.4', 'Cube.5', 'Cube.6', 'Cube.7']
Edited First list ['Cube', 'Cube.1', 'Cube.2', 'Cube.3', 'Cube.4', 'Cube.5', 'Cube.6', 'Ignore_Top_1', 'Ignore_Top_Child_00', 'Ignore_Top_Child_02', 'Cube.7']
Edited Second list ['Cube', 'Cube.1', 'Cube.2', 'Cube.3', 'Ignore_Bot_1', 'Cube.4', 'Cube.6', 'Cube.7', 'Cube.5']
```

Expected output:

```
LINK LIST ['Cube', 'Cube.1', 'Cube.2', 'Cube.3', 'Cube.4', 'Cube.5', 'Cube.6', 'Cube.7']
Edited First list ['Cube', 'Cube.1', 'Cube.2', 'Cube.3', 'Cube.4', 'Cube.5', 'Cube.6', 'Cube.7']
Edited Second list ['Cube', 'Cube.1', 'Cube.2', 'Cube.3', 'Cube.4', 'Cube.6', 'Cube.7', 'Cube.5']
```

Picture of Hierarchy:

[image]

Comment: Never remove items from a container while iterating over it. You could assign a slice: `first_sel_list[:] = [x for x in first_sel_list if x in link_list]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try instead of the not in clause. Instead of worrying about elements not in the list which can sometimes throw issues with removal you only grab the elements with a direct reference.  Its a bit safer over all.

first_sel_list = [name for name in first_sel_list if name in link_list]

second_sel_list = [name for name in second_sel_list if name in link_list]